# How do I add arrowheads without increasing the apparent length of a line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Arrowheads are by default added to the end of a line, which means that the length of the line plus arrowhead is longer than the length of the line alone. This is annoying when I carefully clipped the line to the right length, only to find that I need to realign everything once I add arrowheads.

Is it possible to add arrowheads in such a way that the the length of the line plus the arrowhead is the same as the line alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply click the correct `Align` option on the **Stroke Panel**.

[image: strokes]

If you are using an older version of Illustrator (*which does not have the stroke arrowhead feature*) and using the `Add Arrowhead` **effect**, there is no direct way to alter the placement of the effect. You will need to expand the object appearance and then manually move the arrowhead. If you are using the effect in a version which **does** have the stroke features, stop using the effect.

Comment: Since I am using an older version, I guess I need to learn to live with it. Thanks for the easy-to-understand answer!